# I'm encountering an issue while trying to install Pinecone in Python 3.12, and I receive the following error message:

Tags: python-3.x, database, vector, langchain, pinecone

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
DEPRECATION: Loading egg at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/playsound-1.3.0-py3.12.egg is deprecated. pip 24.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use pip for package installation.. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12330
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pinecone (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pinecone

I've already tried upgrading pip, creating a virtual environment, and installing Pinecone, but the issue persists. Python 3.12 is my current version. Are there any known compatibility issues with Pinecone and Python 3.12, or is there something else I might be missing in the installation process? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.